# C++: using deque member functions inside a class stack

Tags: c++, initialization, deque

I am having trouble with stacking values for a deque object defined in a template class stack. When initializing a class stack object and use the push_back() member function of the STL deque class on the initialized object and read the number of elements inside the stack I get zero, yet the terminal told me it pushed values into it. It looks as follows:

Stack header file

```
#ifndef STACK_HH 
#define STACK_HH

#include <iostream>
#include <deque>

template<class T>
class Stack {

    public: 
        Stack(): s() {   // <-- creating an empty deque s
            s.size() ;   
            nitems() ;
            empty() ;
        }

        ~Stack() {                          
            nitems() ;
            empty() ;
        }

        //Member functions
        int nitems() { return s.size() ; }
        bool empty() { return (s.size()==0) ; }

        void push_back(T c) {
            s[s.size()] = c ;  
        }

        T back() {
            return s[s.size()] ;  
        }

        void pop_back() { 
            if (empty()) {
                std::cout << "Stack::pop() Error: stack is empty" << std::endl ;
            }    
        }

    private:
        std::deque<T> s ;

};

#endif
```

Main script

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
#include "Stack.h" 

using namespace std ;

// Main
int main() {

    int LEN = 10;

    Stack<double> s ;

    // Write doubles into Stack
    for (int i=0 ; i<LEN ; i++) {           
        cout << "pushing value " << i*i << " in stack s" << endl ;
        s.push_back(i*i) ;
    }

    // Count doubles in fifo
    cout << s.nitems() << " value(s) in stack" << endl ;

    return 0 ;
}
```

I was wondering if I should define the deque push_back(), back() and pop_back() functions differently in my Stack header file. Something like void deque < T > ::push_back() and similar for the other ones. But this did not solve it as I already was expecting yet using s.pushback() did not work either.

Any help in solving this problem is kindly appreciated.

EDIT:

Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed use directly the `deque` methods like that:

```
template<class T>
class Stack {

    public: 
        Stack(): s() {   // <-- creating an empty deque s
        }

        ~Stack() {                          
        }

        //Member functions
        int nitems() const { return s.size() ; }
        bool empty() const { return s.empty() ; }

        void push_back(const T& c) {
            s.push_back(c) ;  
        }

        const T& back() {
            return s.back();  
        }

        void pop_back() { 
            if (empty()) {
                std::cout << "Stack::pop() Error: stack is empty" << std::endl ;
            }
            s.pop_back();
        }

    private:
        std::deque<T> s ;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not `std::stack`?

---

Assigning to `s[s.size()]` doesn't add new elements:

> Notes
>
> Unlike std::map::operator[], this operator never inserts a new element into the container.

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/operator_at.

Use `s.push_back(new_element)` to add new element.

---

Last element is `s[s.size() - 1]` or, better, `s.back()`.

---

`s.size()`, `s.size()` and `empty()` in constructor and destructor do nothing.